# Use of UC3843BD1G for current measurement

Tags: current-measurement

I was trying to develop an accurate current measuring circuit. So I opened up a multimeter for some reference. In which I found this UC3843BD1G Current Mode PWM Controller. Can this chip help me in building the current measuring circuit?

I am not able to understand the precise use of this  UC3843BD1G Current mode PWM Controller chip. The datasheets also confuse me.
Here's a link to the datasheet. [UC3843BD1G datasheet](http://www.alldatasheet.com/view.jsp?Searchword=Uc3843bd1g&gclid=CjwKCAiAkrTjBRAoEiwAXpf9CRfnKVG4b8Mzqa4QNFWr6cPKLo6fCo0cEYqhq690wjcP0E5CTVv_qRoCKXMQAvD_BwE).

Can someone explain to me what is its actual use?

Comment: it is difficult to guess what the actual use of the chip is in the multimeter  ....... why did you link alldatasheet.com instead of the manufacturer webpage?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a current measuring chip. It is a switch mode power supply chip that can be used to convert DC voltage from battery to DC voltage for the chips.

Comment: Ok. So it is kind of an advanced and stable voltage regulator, which protects the chip from high voltages.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet explains it:

> The UC3842B, UC3843B series are high performance fixed
>   frequency current mode controllers. They are specifically designed for
>   Off−Line and DC−DC converter applications offering the designer a
>   cost−effective solution with minimal external components.

Presumably your multimeter is using this to generate a voltage - possibly a negative one - other than that supplied by the battery.

It is not the right chip for an accurate current measuring circuit.